# What's the difference between a null pointer and a void pointer?

Tags: c, pointers

Whats the difference between a **Null pointer** & a **Void pointer**?

Comment: These are two different concepts, you cannot compare them. What the difference between the skunk and the moonlight?

Comment: the moon* doesn't smell&

Comment: @qrdl The difference between the skunk and the moonlight --> even though both have a dark side and a light side, not knowing the difference affects dating and the gene pool.

Answer (score 122, accepted):

*Null pointer* is a special reserved **value** of a pointer. A pointer of any type has such a reserved value. Formally, each specific pointer type (`int *`, `char *` etc.) has its own dedicated null-pointer value. Conceptually, when a pointer has that null value it is not pointing anywhere.

*Void pointer* is a specific pointer **type** - `void *` - a pointer that points to some data location in storage, which doesn't have any specific type.

So, once again, *null pointer* is a **value**, while *void pointer* is a **type**. These concepts are totally different and non-comparable. That essentially means that your question, as stated, is not exactly valid. It is like asking, for example, "What is the difference between a triangle and a car?".

Comment: @Pavitar, It's useful as a marker. For example, to indicate a pointer that has not been allocated memory or to mark the end(s) of a linked list.

Comment: You can and you should use Null Pointers. 
For example, If malloc can't allocate memory, it returns a null pointer. It is a good practice to put your pointers to null after free() 'em to avoid Dangling Pointers 

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dangling_pointer

Comment: @Pavitar:  The null pointer constant is guaranteed to be invalid, and it's identifiable.  You can't confuse it with any valid pointer.  Therefore, it can be used as a signal of failure, or a marker that there's no more data, or that a pointer doesn't point anywhere, or anything like that.

Comment: "null pointer" vs "null-pointer"  I see you use two words as a descriptive noun and a hyphenated word as an adjective clause for the noun exception.
This looks and sounds correct to my 'mind's ear"; but is it actually grammatically correct?

Comment: @DavidThornley  Detail: The  _null pointer constant_ is a value.  it could have the value of `0` and type of `int`.  A  _null pointer_ is "guaranteed to compare unequal to a pointer to any object or function".

Comment: For pascal users: void* is equivalent of "Pointer" and null is equivalent of "nil"

Answer (score 15):

They are two different concepts: "void pointer" is a type (void *). "null pointer" is a pointer that has a value of zero (NULL). Example:

```
void *pointer = NULL;
```

That's a NULL void pointer.

Answer (score 6):

A null pointer is guaranteed to not compare equal to a pointer to any object. It's actual value is system dependent and may vary depending on the type. To get a null `int` pointer you would do

```
int* p = 0;
```

A null pointer will be returned by `malloc` on failure.

We can test if a pointer is null, i.e. if `malloc` or some other function failed simply by testing its boolean value:

```
if (p) {
    /* Pointer is not null */
} else {
    /* Pointer is null */
}
```

A void pointer can point to any type and it is up to you to handle how much memory the referenced objects consume for the purpose of dereferencing and pointer arithmetic.

Answer (score 4):

Void refers to the type.  Basically the type of data that it points to is unknown.

Null refers to the value.  It's essentially a pointer to nothing, and is invalid to use.

Answer (score 2):

A null pointer points has the value `NULL` which is typically 0, but in any case a memory location which is invalid to dereference. A void pointer points at data of type void. The word "void" is not an indication that the data referenced by the pointer is invalid or that the pointer has been nullified.

Comment: `NULL` in C is either `0` or `(void *)0`, and in C++ `NULL` is always `0`. The implementation's internal representation for a null pointer might not be 0 (as in all bits cleared), however.

Answer (score 1):

Usually a null pointer (which can be of any type, including a void pointer !) points to:

- the address 0, against which most CPU instructions sets can do a very fast compare-and-branch (to check for uninitialized or invalid pointers, for instance) with optimal code size/performance for the ISA.
- an address that's illegal for user code to access (such as 0x00000000 in many cases), so that if a code actually tries to access data at or near this address, the OS or debugger can easily stop or trap a program with this bug.

A void pointer is usually a method of cheating or turning-off compiler type checking, for instance if you want to return a pointer to one type, or an unknown type, to use as another type.  For instance malloc() returns a void pointer to a type-less chunk of memory, the type of which you can cast to later use as a pointer to bytes, short ints, double floats, typePotato's, or whatever.

Comment: Whether the null pointer points to address 0 is completely irrelevant to its proper use, although it's nice if it does so if you're debugging and examining variable values.  Nor is it necessary to cause any sort of fault, although I think that's a good feature.  It's guaranteed to compare equal to any other null pointer value of the same type, and guaranteed to compare unequal to any valid pointer, and that's the real use.

Answer (score 1):

`NULL` is a value that is valid for any pointer type.  It represents the absence of a value.

A void pointer is a type.  Any pointer type is convertible to a void pointer hence it can point to any value.  This makes it good for general storage but bad for use.  By itself it cannot be used to access a value.  The program must have extra context to understand the type of value the void pointer refers to before it can access the value.

Answer (score 1):

Null pointers and void pointers are completely different from each other. If we request the operating system(through malloc() in c langauge) to allocate memory for a particular data type  then the operating system allocates memory in heap (if space is available in heap) and sends the address of the memory which was allocated.

When memory is allocated by os in heap then we can assign this address value in any pointer type variable of that data type. This pointer is then called a void pointer until it is not taken for any process.

When the space is not available in heap then the operating system certainly allocates memory and sends an address value of that location but this memory is not allocated in heap by the os because there is no space in heap,in this case this memory is allocated by the os in the system memory.. This memory can not be accessed by the user hence when we assign this address value in a pointer then this pointer is known as null pointer, and we cannot use this pointer. In the case of void pointer we can use it for any process in any programming language.

Comment: If the C library fails to allocate on the heap, either because the os won't give it memory, or because the heap is so fragmented it can't get a large enough block it will return a null pointer. I don't know what you're talking about wrt system memory. Also, I'm not sure what "is then called a void pointer until it is not taken for any process." What do you mean by "not taken for any process"?

Answer (score 1):

Both `void` and `null` pointers point to a memory location in the end.

A `null` pointer points to place (in a memory segment) which is **usually** the 0th address of memory segment. It is almost all about how the underlying OS treat that "reserved" memory location (an implementation detail) when you try to access it to read/write or dereference. For example, that particular memory location can be marked as "non-accessible" and throws an expection when it's accessed.

A `void` pointer can point to anywhere and potentially represent any type (primitive, reference-type, and **including `null`**).

As someone nicely put above, `null` pointer represents a **value** whereas `void*` represents a **type** more than a value.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think [AnT's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3581630/3982001) is correct.

1. `NULL` is just a pointer constant, otherwise how could we have `ptr = NULL`.
2. As `NULL` is a pointer, what's its type. I think the type is just `(void *)`, otherwise how could we have both `int * ptr = NULL` and `(user-defined type)* ptr = NULL`.  `void` type is actually a universal type.
3. Quoted in "C11(ISO/IEC 9899:201x) §6.3.2.3 Pointers Section 3":

   > An integer constant expression with the value 0, or such an expression cast to type  void *, is called a null pointer constant

So simply put: `NULL` pointer is a void pointer constant.

Comment: We can have `void *ptr = NULL;` even if `NULL` is an `int` as then `NULL` is converted from whatever type it is to `void *` as part of the assignment and that conversion is well specified.

Answer (score 0):

A Null pointer has the value 0. void pointer is a generic pointer introduced by ANSI. Generic pointer can hold the address of any data type.