# What is the difference between a void pointer and a NULL pointer?

Tags: c++, c

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What's the difference between a null pointer and a void pointer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3581585/whats-the-difference-between-a-null-pointer-and-a-void-pointer)

What is the difference between a pointer to void and a NULL pointer in C? Or are they the same?

Comment: Exact duplicate of [What's the difference between a null pointer and a void pointer?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3581585/whats-the-difference-between-a-null-pointer-and-a-void-pointer). Please use search before posting questions.

Answer (score 10):

In **C**, there is `void`, `void` pointer and `NULL` pointer.

1. `void` is **absence of type**. I.E. a function returning a `void` type is a function that returns nothing.
2. `void` pointer: is a pointer to a memory location whose type can be anything: a structure, an int, a float, you name it.
3. A `NULL` pointer is a pointer to location `0x00`, that is, no location. Pointing to nothing.

Examples:

`void` function:

```
void printHello()
{
   printf("Hello");
}
```

`void` pointer:

```
void *malloc(size_t si)
{
    // malloc is a function that could return a pointer to anything
}
```

`NULL` pointer:

```
char *s = NULL;
// s pointer points to nowhere (nothing)
```

Answer (score 7):

`void` is a datatype. `void*` is just a pointer to an undefined type. A `void*` can be set to any memory location. A NULL pointer is a any pointer which is set to NULL (0).

So yes, they are different, because a void pointer is a datatype, and a NULL pointer refers to any pointer which is set to NULL.

Answer (score 5):

Pointer to void is a pointer to an unspecified type. Ie. Just a pointer. It can still be a valid pointer, but we don't know what it points to (eg. A function might take a void pointer as a parameter, and then interpret the type according to a different parameter)

NULL is an 'empty' pointer. Not valid, can be used to specify a pointer to nothing / not set. It is a value whilst void is a type.