# Understanding null pointers in C

Tags: c, pointers

So imagine I have this

```
main() {
    int a = 5;
    int *p;
    printf("p: %d", (void*)p);
}
```

Why would I have to cast the *p in the printf statement? But if I do this...

```
p = &a;
printf("p: %d", *p);
```

This time I don't have to cast?

So my question is that do I need to cast void everytime to a null pointer?

Comment: I'm rusty with C but i'm going to take a stab and say because you implicitly initialized the pointer with the `p= &p;` statement?

Comment: I meant to say  p = &a;

Comment: To print the address of a pointer you sould use `%p`  instead of `%d`, the `%p` format expect a cast `(void *)`

Comment: I don't want to get the address of the pointer. I want to dereference it so I retrieve what is stored in memory.

Comment: @AlterMann what happens when I cast it with void?

Comment: @YusufJama, you are invoking undefined behavior, you can not print an address with `%d`

Comment: @AlterMann no it is a reference to an int..that is what the pointer is. So when I am saying (void *)p in the first print statement, it returns a value? As in I am not worried about the memory address...I want the value stored in that memory location.

Comment: Is a reference to an int, yes, but `p` is not initialized,  so you can not dereference the pointer

Comment: Ok I get that so far BUT what does (void *) mean?

Comment: You might like to read on the type `void`, on how to define a pointer, on the de-reference operator `*` and  on `printf()` in general and its conversion specifiers in particular, if then any issues are still open feel free to come back. Casting also might be of your interest.

Comment: And btw, I do not see any null-pointers in your question.

Comment: Following @alk, OP might be interested in this SO question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3581585/whats-the-difference-between-a-null-pointer-and-a-void-pointer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To print out pointer values (`NULL` or otherwise), you must use the `%p` conversion specifier, which expects its corresponding argument to have type `void *`:

```
printf("p = %p\n", (void *) p );
```

This is probably the only time in C you need to *explicitly* cast a pointer value to `void *` (if it isn't already `void *`, anyway).  The reason why is a combination of how `printf` reads its arguments, default type promotions in variadic functions, and a couple of other things that I have yet to figure out how to explain well.

Note that you are casting the value of `p` (the pointer), not the thing that it points to.

In the second print statement,

```
printf("*p = %d\n", *p );
```

you are printing the value of the thing that `p` *points to*, which is an integer.  The *expression* `*p` has type `int`, which is what the `%d` conversion specifier expects.

Answer (score 2):

In the first example you are printing the value of the pointer itself, but are using the wrong format specifier.

```
printf("p: %d", (void*)p);
```

should be

```
printf("p: %p", (void*)p);
```

The reason is, an `int` specified by `%d` might not be the same size as a pointer. The reason for the cast, is because `%p` prints the value of a `void*` pointer. But note: in your example `int *p` is unintialised, so printing its value is useless.

In the second example you are printing the value pointed to, by the pointer, and no cast is necessary, because the types are consistent.

```
printf("p: %d", *p);
```

Comment: What I want is what is stored in memory..not the memory address. I am trying to dereference it...are you saying I can't dereference a null pointer?

Comment: @YusufJama yes. A `void*` pointer points to an indeterminate object, so you cannot dereference it. Functions such as `malloc()` return a `void*` pointer so that it can be assigned to any data type. But conversely, `printf` using the format spec `%p` needs a `void*` pointer, by definition.

Comment: What if the pointer is set as p = &a? Why wouldn't I need a cast void?

Comment: "Deferencing" a pointer is fetching the thing it points to. If it's not pointing to anything (either by virtue of being a void * type or by having a NULL value), then you can't fetch what doesn't exist.

Comment: @YusufJama as explained, if you are using `int` type all is consistent, no cast required. But to print the pointer address value itself, it has to be cast to `void*`, although you *might* "get away with" not doing so, or using a different format specifier, and such might "work" on your platform, happily, but not by design.

Comment: Ok so what is what is stored inside what that pointer points to. Let's say that the pointer is not initialized. If I cast with void*, why am I getting a value returned? Is that a random memory location?

Comment: *random* is  not quite the right word because that's a valid concept. Perhaps "spurious". If the pointer is not initialised, anything you do with it is **undefined behaviour**.

Comment: Ok that makes sense...even though it is not initialized, it could be whatever was stored in memory previously that is being returned. Would that be a way of saying it?

Comment: Well yes, there was *some value* from some previous use. But it's not useful. In fact using it, may cause all sorts of trouble, especially with a pointer.