# va_arg always runs 4 times

Tags: c, variadic-functions

I am learning stdarg.h in c i am trying to print all arguments passed to function without knowing how many arguments are there but yet i have not come up with solution, during this this happened, no matter what i pass to strtest.
It always print 0. 1. 2. 3.

```
void strtest(char *fmt, ...){
    va_list argp;
    int i = 0;

    va_start(argp, fmt);

    while(va_arg(argp, char*))
        printf("%d\t", i++ );

    va_end(argp);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    strtest("s");
    printf("\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example showing one way to pass an unknown number of arguments.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdarg.h>

void print (char *first, ...)
{
    va_list argptr;
    char *next;
    va_start (argptr, first);
    next = first;
    while (next) {
        printf ("%s\n", next);
        next = va_arg(argptr, char*);
        }
    va_end (argptr);
}

int main(void)
{
    print("hello","world", NULL);      // NULL as sentinel
    return 0;
}
```

Program output

```
hello
world
```

Perhaps you can adapt this to your needs using `int` arguments.

Answer (score 5):

There's no standard mechanism that will tell you the number of arguments passed to a varargs function. Functions like `printf()` work because they can determine the number of arguments by examining the format string.

Comment: See this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1688942/variable-arguments-in-c-how-to-get-values-with-a-generic-type for way to do it.  I'm not sure this qualifies as standard but depending on environment make work for the OP.

Comment: @JJF That question is about argument types, not number of arguments. Is there a specific answer there that tells how to get the count?

Comment: See the part with va_start(ap, count);
    for(i=0 ; i < count; i++)  @Barmar

Comment: @JJF That requires passing a `count` argument before the varying arguments.

Comment: Oh you're right @Barmar.  You could count them similar to the MSDN sample I think https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kb57fad8.aspx.  Again I doubt it's standard but I'm pretty sure there is similar way with Linux.  Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

This is the definition of stdarg.h in the ISO 9899 WG14 n1256

> The header <stdarg.h> declares a type and defines four macros, for advancing
>   through a list of arguments whose number and types are not known to the called function
>   when it is translated

You have to pass the number of arguments, and possibly the types as well,  to the caller. This doesn't have to be done by directly passing the number of arguments, there are other methods such as the one used in printf.

Comment: Or include a `NULL` sentinel.

Comment: or parse something that functions like a format string (doesn't need to be a format string)

Comment: @WeatherVane The `NULL` sentinel only works if all the arguments are pointers of the same type.

Comment: @Barmar I didn't think `NULL` was type-specific, but I posted an answer in which they are all the same type.

Comment: @WeatherVane NULL is a void pointer, and there are some systems where void pointers have a different representation than an int pointer. http://c-faq.com/null/machexamp.html

Comment: I'm lost now why you are comparing chalk and cheese. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3581585/whats-the-difference-between-a-null-pointer-and-a-void-pointer

Comment: @WeatherVane Doesn't uncast NULL default to void* when you pass it as a variadic argument? If you have pointers to different types, the representation issues still exists.

Comment: What else could it possibly represent, since there is no other information? And why don't *all* pointers passed do likewise?

Answer (score 0):

You could pass a sentinel to the function like this

```
strtest("s", (char*)0);
```

such that the function can notice that it is at the end of the argument list.

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the man page for stdarg, va_arg includes this text

> If there is no next argument, or if type is not compatible with  the
>   type  of  the  actual  next  argument  (as promoted according to the
>   default argument promotions), random errors will occur.

Unless you call strtest with a NULL as the last argument, va_arg will just keep reading until it hits something that makes it stop. Think of what you are doing right now as equivalent to reading an array outside its bounds.

I'm surprised it was running 4 times no matter what though. I would have expected the count to be equal to the number of args you passed to strtest plus 2 or more.